# Blank screen appears on chrome when I run(F5) the Flutter web app (I use VScode)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I am running a Flutter Web app on chrome using VScode (**F5**) and it opens up a new tab with title same as that of the project name but the screen is blank. In the **Debug Console**, it says `Launching lib\main.dart on chrome in debug mode...` and doesn't display anything else. I tried the command `flutter run -d web` and that runs fine. How do I make it work if I run or press F5 in vscode?
[VScode Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVmC2.png)
[Chrome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3dKq.png)

Comment: try flutter run -d --release

Comment: Try checking this out: [Building Web Application with Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web).

Comment: Can you add your code here? and also the errors you are getting in the terminal

Comment: @NileshSenta that didn't work for me

Comment: @Alok I tried 'flutter create .' and yet didn't work

Comment: @HardikKumar It's the default flutter app. I have uploaded the error image in the question. Debug console is stuck in Launching lib\main.dart on chrome in debug mode... No error in terminal coz I ran it using F5 not terminal

Comment: my problem solved when i ran it from vscode. press run and debug from left panel or press f5. no need to any change setting or command.

Comment: flutter --version ====>Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f4abaa0735 (3 months ago) • 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
Engine • revision 241c87ad80
Tools • Dart 2.13.4

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue too and it was fixed by disabling the hardware acceleration in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal, try `flutter upgrade`

then `flutter run -v`

It happens with flutter, sometimes it takes very long to build an app

Answer (score 1):

Try running in the terminal:

- flutter channel dev
- flutter upgrade
- flutter run -d chrome

If it still shows you a blank page terminate the current server 'ctrl + c'.

Then run

flutter run -d web

and the terminal will provide you with a new localhost URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
checkerboardOffscreenLayers: true // in my case this cause blank page
```

Answer (score -1):

add this `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`